# Proof of Bessel function.

Tags: complex-analysis

From Churchill and Brown:

> Let $z$ be any complex number, and let $C$ denote the unit circle:
>   $$w = e^{i\phi}$$
>   in the $w$ plane. Then use that contour expression (5), Sec. 66, for the coefficients in a Laurent series, adapted to such series about the origin in the w plane, to show that:
>   $$\exp \left[\frac{z}{2}\left(w - \frac{1}{w}\right)\right] = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty J_n(z)w^n$$.
>   where
>   $$J_n(z) = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \exp [-i(n\phi - z\sin {\phi})]d\phi$$

So I have concluded from "expression (5)" that:

$$J_n(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{\exp \left[\frac{z}{2}\left(w - \frac{1}{w}\right)\right]}{w^{n+1}}$$

Re writing $w-\frac{1}{w}$ as $2i\sin (\phi)$ and $w^{n+1}$ as $e^{in\phi}e^{i\phi}$ you get:

\begin{align}
J_n(z) &= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{\exp\left[\frac{z}{2}(2i\sin(\phi)\right]}{e^{in\phi}e^{i\phi}} \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{\exp\left[z(-i)(n\phi - \sin(\phi) \right]}{e^{i\phi}}
\end{align}

This looks pretty close but I don't exactly know what to do to get rid of the rogue $e^{i\phi}$ and $z$ term...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of mistakes in your equations

1. The first expression for $J_n(z)$ in the box is missing a factor, it should be

$$
J_n(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}d\phi\;\exp[-i(n\phi - z \sin\phi)]
$$

2. Probably the most important one, you are missing the integration variable in **all** of the steps of your derivation:

   \begin{eqnarray*}
   \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C dw\;\frac{\exp[z(w - 1/w)/2]}{w^{n + 1}} &=& \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} d\phi\;\frac{de^{i\phi}}{d\phi} \frac{\exp[i z\sin\phi - in\phi]}{e^{i\phi}} \\
   &=& \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}d\phi\;\exp[i(z\sin\phi - n\phi)] \\
   &=& J_n(z)
    \end{eqnarray*}