# Laurent Series of Bessel functions

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Bessel functions are the solutions $y(x)$ of Bessel's differential equation
$$
x^2 \frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d}x^2}+x\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}+(x^2-\alpha^2)y = 0
$$

The Bessel functions of the first kind, $J_\alpha$ can be defined as
$$
J_\alpha(x)=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^m}{m!\Gamma(m+\alpha+1)}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2m+\alpha}
$$

On the other hand, there is a Laurent series about $J_n$,
$$
\exp\left(\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\left(t-\frac{1}{t}\right)\right) = \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}J_n(x)t^n
$$

If I have to prove the Laurent series, I need to compute line integrals by definition of the series, which bothers me.

Could someone please show me how to calculate the line integral?

Comment: you can expand $\exp\dfrac{xt}{2}\cdot\exp\dfrac{-x}{2t}$.

Comment: @Nosrati you mean compute the series for each term?

Comment: I think you want this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2002922/proof-of-bessel-function?rq=1

Comment: @Nosrati This is something I need. Thanks!